# Using double quotes in a command assigning it in a variable with double quotes bash

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, double-quotes

`dir="$(find -L "${1:-.}" -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null|fzf -0)"`

why it works even if quoting end is unspecified in bash. This should've show error but worked perfectly.WHY?

Previously I tried
`dir="$(find -L \"${1:-.}\" -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null|fzf -0)"` but it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` establishes a new quoting context. After the `$(`, the next `"` is an *opening* quote, not the closing quote paired with your opening quote before the `$(`.

As the entire right-hand side is a single command substitution, you don't need the outer quotes at all, as the RHS is not subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion, the prevention of which are the two reasons you would otherwise quote it.

```
dir=$(find -L "${1:-.}" -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null | fzf -0)
```

is sufficient.